# Can Python ctypes callback function return a python class instance?

Tags: python, ctypes

```
from ctypes import *
class CTest(Structure):
    pass

def get_test(id):
    c = CTest()
    return c

func_type = CFUNCTYPE(CTest, c_int)
test_callback = func_type(get_test)
```

When I run this script, I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\test\ctypes_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    test_callback = func_type(get_test)
TypeError: invalid result type for callback function
```

What's wrong in the script?

Comment: Just as a note: its a bad practice to `import *`. You should `import ctypes`, it may take little more effort to type `ctypes.Structure` but you know that  its from the ctypes module which helps avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctypes.pyobject` :

```
import ctypes
#from ctypes import *
class CTest(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = []
    a = 10

    def __init__(self):
        ctypes.Structure.__init__(self)

def get_test(id):
    return CTest()


func_type = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE( ctypes.py_object , ctypes.c_int ) 
test_callback = func_type( get_test )

print test_callback(1).a
```

> > **>> 10**